# Lag operator calculation(differencing) with polynomial trend

Tags: time-series, arima, differences

I am trying to show that

*((1-L)^n)t^n = n!*

I have tried to simplify the calculation using hypergeometric series but it did not work out.

Could anyone give a hint about this?

Comment: Use induction on $n.$